# Get a enum uppercase values version derivated from another enum

Tags: typescript, enums

I have the following enum in TypeScript:

```
export enum OrderState {
  stateA: "State_A",
  stateB: "State_B"
}
```

And i would like to generate without create another enum the uppercase version of the same enum:

```
export enum OrderStateUpper {
  stateA: "STATE_A",
  stateB: "STATE_B"
}
```

it is possible using advanced types?

I created a derivated type using the following approach, but I would like to derivate in another enum:

```
export type OrderStateUppercase = Uppercase<CreditOrderState>
```

Comment: No, but you could use a regular object instead.

Comment: You can't generate "genuine" enums, but you could do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wkky1W) where you define both an object and a type.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz if you reply, to notify me)

Comment: Thank you both of you, the second option from @jcalz would work if I could use Object.fromEntries() method but according the version limitation for the app is not possible. Any other option?

Comment: If you have ES version limitations you should [edit] the question to specify your constraints... but I'd say that's out of scope here. It's easy enough to polyfill `Object.fromEntries()` or [write your own](https://tsplay.dev/WvGO3w).   What do you want me to do here?  (pls continue to mention @jcalz to notify me in replies)